# Emulating multiple click functions or have separate clicked values based on specific areas below or above dataMin and dataMax - highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highstock from highcharts.

I want to capture min and max values based on the area of the chart clicked.

Let's say my current instance of graph have a min of 15 and max of 80 from a range of 1-100 data set.
Now, if I click on any area below 15 I should be able to set a min value in my code. So I would probably want to do something

```
click: function(e) {
     ctrl.minSelected = e.yAxis[0].value;

}
```

Similarly if I click on area above value 80, I want to fire same or another click handler to capture my max value.

First, is this possible in highcharts? Please guide if yes else let me know hwo can I achieve this ? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you assume these are hidden ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a very basic example showing how to get to the values you need. The actual code and logic should not be too hard to figure out from here.

The following code will give you clicked yValue, and the current extreme values in the console. [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/2d6xmk0v/)

```
chart: {
    events: {
        click: function (event) {
            console.log(event.yAxis[0].value);
            console.log(chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes());
            this.update({yAxis: {max: event.yAxis[0].value}}) 
        }
    }
}
```

To explain a bit more:

`event.yAxis[0].value` gives the yValue according to the yAxis, see [API on chart.events.click](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.click).

`chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes()` gives the yAxis extremes, both the graph area extremes and the data(points) extremes, see [API on Axis.getExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.getExtremes)

`this.update` this refers to the chart, update lets you update whatever you may want to on the chart, see [API on Chart.update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.update). Here we use it to set the yAxis max to the value of the location clicked.

Comment: I am looking at the solution. Unfortunately couldn't go through code level yesterday as I was on mobile. Although provided more description at d_paul's answer. I find getExtremes() may prove helpful. But I have a lot to discuss about dataMax, dataMin along with zoomLevel of 1m , 5m, All. They all vary with their output value. Then there is userMin and userMax as well. I think that must be set once I call setExtremes somewhere. Idk, just playing with code and API reference.

Comment: The output of say dataMax gets even variable by setting maxPadding option in yAxis.Say it logs 98 for 1m, 100 for 5mins and 96 for all range every time I click.  It's unpredictable. What's the logic behind?

Comment: upvoted for pointing to getExtremes(). Now all I need to figure out is to determine my clicked point proximity to dataMin or dataMax. So now if my value is near to dataMax I should update my ctrl.maxSelected value to clicked value else the clicked value is my ctrl.minSelected

Answer (score 0):

Simply enable zooming by setting `zoomType` property with 'x', 'y' or 'xy'. You can get min and max of selected area in `selection` event.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.zoomType
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.selection

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/uLsx8pz6/

Comment: Will this give me dynamic value of y-axis? By `min` I mean the point the user clicks on any position below value 15 for instance. Similarly setting max value to whatever user selects above the point 80

Comment: Now I am doing this cause I want to do something as soon as the graph value actually touches these two points. So for example, the 15 and 80 can shift to another high and low. Actually High low will be better terms to describe instances of 15 and 80. Min and max be the user selections

Comment: Oh no. I get why would you post about selection. `based on area of chart selected` was leading into this solution. I corrected selected to *clicked* to avoid any further confusion. So hope it's clear that there is no manual selection but there are hypothetical below and above section based on dataMin or dataMax value. Now, over a couple of hours I am more familiar with these API terms . Cheers mate and I apologise for that misleading word.
Cheers !

Comment: And I sort of polished my question title based on my better understanding of the highcharts terminology